# Limit usage of AWS unauth cognito user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I am making a web application where a user can get a text (they have to enter) read.
The user doesn't have to identify / login before using the service.

The text is read thank to AWS Polly (with a cognito unauth role called via javascript by the user browser).
I did followed this tutorial:
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html

Nonetheless I would like to give a kind of quota to the users.
I am afraid a single user uses the service too many times because I will have to pay for the many AWS Polly requests.

I don't know how to create quotas for each unauth user...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, this is impossible.

AWS Cognito controls whether or not a set of credentials is allowed to make a particular API call. The credentials can be time-limited and API calls can be restricted by things like IP address, but it is not possible to limits API calls by quantity. This is true both for authenticated and unauthenticated users.

You can overcome this problem by having users call an API through AWS API Gateway which will trigger your own code on AWS Lambda. The Lambda function then verifies whether to allow the action and then makes the API call on behalf of the client.

Passing through the API Gateway will also allow you to have more control on the user actions (tracking per-user usage, restricting functionalities).

Comment: So basically, you are saying that if I put to production this AWS documentation example; any malicious user of my "browser based polly website"  would be able to use the service any number of time and I will have to pay for it ? I mean, any user could create a script that perform 2 000 000 request per day and thus cost me a lot without any kind of automatic stopping mechanism from AWS ? If it is the case, I am surprised that AWS doesn't emit any warning of potential cost in the documentation ! https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html

Comment: Well, you can do that kind of control from the API Gateway. But it is exactly like that, any user could perform those kind of requests and you will pay for it. I had the same problem and created CloudWatch alarms and rule-based actions to prevent this kind of attacks.

Comment: Many thanks for the possible solutions. Would you have more details about the second one (rule-based actions to prevent this kind of attacks) ? I understand that I can create an alarm on CW but how can this alarm prevent this kind of attacj ?